# How to plot predictions of binomial GLM that has both continuous and categorical variables

Tags: r, plot, prediction, glm

I have a binomial GLM in R, with several predictors that are both continuous and categorical.

The response variable is "Presence", which is binary (0/1). 
Length is a continuous variable, while all others are categorical.

I am trying to plot predictions for each of the variables in the final model, particularly for "length", but I'm having difficulties.

My data are the following:

```
MyData<-structure(list(site = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("R1a", "R1b", "R2", "Za", "Zb"
), class = "factor"), species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Monogyna", "Other", 
"Prunus", "Rosa"), class = "factor"), aspect = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("East", 
"Flat", "North", "South", "West"), class = "factor"), length = c(260L, 
60L, 60L, 40L, 240L, 80L, 30L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 
35L, 120L, 60L, 500L, 40L, 20L, 70L, 250L, 80L, 50L, 130L, 350L, 
170L, 50L, 60L, 90L, 50L, 40L, 110L, 60L, 70L, 70L, 500L, 140L, 
50L, 50L, 360L, 50L, 150L, 60L, 270L, 280L, 130L, 130L, 50L, 
60L, 30L, 70L, 70L, 60L, 400L, 20L, 30L, 70L, 160L, 340L, 100L, 
210L, 60L, 70L, 130L, 50L, 40L, 50L, 80L, 390L, 40L, 110L, 130L, 
40L, 230L, 120L, 70L, 80L, 80L, 90L, 70L, 150L, 120L, 50L, 100L, 
120L, 10L, 40L, 80L, 180L, 160L, 200L, 40L, 70L, 90L, 50L, 40L, 
80L, 80L, 70L, 480L, 90L, 60L, 100L, 140L, 190L, 20L, 70L, 360L, 
70L, 130L, 60L, 50L, 320L, 210L, 130L, 180L, 90L, 20L, 300L, 
90L, 50L, 130L, 70L, 70L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 100L, 20L, 70L, 
100L, 340L, 70L, 110L, 40L, 230L, 200L, 80L, 35L, 110L, 200L, 
50L, 110L, 100L, 50L, 150L, 110L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 70L, 80L, 60L, 
100L, 90L, 40L, 300L, 140L, 180L, 140L, 40L, 190L, 100L, 170L, 
40L, 120L, 15L, 70L, 340L, 40L, 40L, 70L, 60L, 130L, 140L, 170L, 
120L, 90L, 130L, 210L, 50L, 180L, 120L, 100L, 50L, 90L, 70L, 
360L, 80L, 30L, 170L, 70L, 300L, 40L, 130L, 120L, 90L, 40L, 40L, 
140L, 80L, 400L, 70L, 80L, 60L, 420L, 320L, 200L, 40L, 50L, 70L, 
50L, 80L, 50L, 110L, 100L, 120L, 170L, 20L, 110L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 
30L, 90L, 150L, 80L, 40L, 90L, 300L, 30L, 70L, 50L, 90L, 200L
), sun = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("Half", "Shade", "Sun"), class = "factor"), 
    leaf = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Large", "Medium", "Scarce", "Small"), class = "factor"), 
    Presence = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L
    )), .Names = c("site", "species", "aspect", "length", "sun", 
"leaf", "Presence"), row.names = c(NA, 236L), class = "data.frame")
```

(note that this is a reduced dataset, and I have already removed variables that were dropped during model selection)

The optimal model is:

```
model <- glm(Presence ~ site + species + aspect + length + sun 
                + leaf, data=MyData, family=binomial)
```

I tried the following, but it wants the other variables too, so I get an error:

```
plot(MyData$length, MyData$Presence)
mydat1 <- data.frame(length = seq(from = 10, to = 500, by = 1)
pred1 <- predict(model, newdata = mydat1, type = "response")
lines(MyData$length, pred1)
```

So I tried specifying all variables, but then it only puts a horizontal line through the presence data points (and that means I need to specify all possible combinations of factor variables I suppose):

```
plot(MyData$length, MyData$Presence)
mydat2 <- data.frame(length = seq(from = 10, to = 500, by = 1), 
                     site = "R1a", 
                     species = "Monogyna",
                     aspect = "Flat", 
                     sun = "Sun", 
                     leaf = "Scarce")
pred2 <- predict(model, newdata = mydat2, type = "response")
lines(MyData$length, pred2)
```

Finally, I tried the following code:

```
pred <- predict(model, type = "response")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in names(MyData)){
   plot(MyData[,i],pred,xlab=i, ylab="Probability")
}
```

I am confused by this last one, as I am not able to obtain the curve, plus the output gives me predicted values for variables that are not even in the optimal model.

What I should expect under this model, is a sinusoidal curve, I suppose. But that's not what I'm getting.

How can I produce a meaningful plot of predictions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `effects` package for some easier results for a single predictor. Here is how:

```
library(effects)
fit <- as.data.frame(effect('length', model, xlevels = 100))
```

Plotting is easy (although note the overplotting):

```
plot(MyData$length, MyData$Presence)
lines(fit$length, fit$fit)
```

[image]

Or we can use `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_count(aes(length, Presence), MyData) +
  geom_line(aes(length, fit), fit, size = 1, col = 'red') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(length, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), fit, alpha = 0.15) +
  scale_size_area()
```

[image]

We can see that the effect of length is not very impressive.

Comment: Thank you @Axeman, much appreciated! 

How would you interpret this plot though? (I don't mean in terms of the plot itself, but in relation to the fact that several other variables in the model are factors) 
Is this the effect of length given a mean value for all other predictors? Or for a baseline level of other predictors...?

Also, I don't know if you're familiar with the 3rd piece of code I gave, but if you are, are you able to comment on that?